# Using radio buttons with 2-way-binding and iteration in ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I wonder if it is possible to use ractive.js' 2-way-binding with a nested iteration section. What I need is to iterate over the answerOptions for each calibration. My template looks like this:

```
<script id="calibration-view" type="text/html">
<div id="calibrations">
    {{#each calibrations :num}}
    <div id="calibration">
        <div id="answer-options-{{num}}">
            {{#each answerOptions}}}
            <label><input type="radio" name="{{bindThisValuePerAnswerOption}}" value={{id}}>{{option}}</label>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    <button on-click="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

What currently happens is that all inputs will have the same binding of:

```
name="{{bindThisValuePerAnswerOption}}"
```

I've been trying to solve this for a while now and hope there is a way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a `<Calibration>` component, as that creates a new context for the `name` binding. Unfortunately there's a bug in the most recent stable version that prevents this from working – it's fixed in the edge version (which will be released as 0.8 in the near future), used below.

```js
Ractive.components.Calibration = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    <div class="calibration">
      <div id="answer-options-{{num}}">
        {{#each answerOptions}}
          <label><input type="radio" name="{{selected}}" value={{id}}>{{option}}</label>
        {{/each}}
     </div>
    </div>
  `
});

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: `
    <div id="calibrations">
      {{#each calibrations :num}}
     <Calibration selected='{{selections[num]}}'/>
      {{/each}}
      <button on-click="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
  
    <pre>{{JSON.stringify(selections)}}</pre>
  `,
  data: {
    selections: [
      'b', 'f'
    ],
    calibrations: [
      {
        answerOptions: [
          { id: 'a', option: 'A' },
          { id: 'b', option: 'B' },
          { id: 'c', option: 'C' }
        ]
      },
      {
        answerOptions: [
          { id: 'd', option: 'D' },
          { id: 'e', option: 'E' },
          { id: 'f', option: 'F' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.min.js'></script>
<main></main>
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer!